# Starting out with D&D from complete scratch

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, new-players, new-gm

I'm currently planning to get myself and three other friends into D&D, so I'm looking for tips on starting out from scratch.

To be clear, by from scratch I mean I don't have any dice, any rulebooks, really anything D&D related, hell, I haven't even really played D&D myself, the most experience I have with D&D is watching other people's campaigns on youtube.

What I'm planning is to create and DM a short campaign just to give my friends a taste of what it's like to play D&D (and because I really want to try it out for myself as well). I'm also planning to put in an NPC/pseudo-PC as a part of the party.

Feel free to give general tips for this, but a few questions that I'd need at most would be:

- What edition should I start with/use?
- What's the best tip you have for DMing?
- What should I do with my campaign? Is what I've got planned viable for completely new players?
- Are there short pre-made campaigns that are great for just jumping in and finish in around 1 or 2 hours?

Thank you!

Comment: Also related: [What do I need to run a 5e campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56252/4563), “5e” referring to the fifth edition of the rules, which is the latest and probably the one you’ve seen in podcasts and the like.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! Congratulations on your new hobby! [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/8610)'s answers are a really good rundown on how to get started. What that question doesn't address, you can include in this question. Also, consider the extent of the [RPG landscape](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/8610)—nothing says your first RPG must be *D&D*! Anyway, welcome, thank you for participating, and have fun!

Comment: also, there are like 10 editions of D&D to choose from!

Comment: Just to be extra-clear, the 4 bulleted questions are, for the most part, beyond the site's scope, being either polls or game recommendations. Of them, were a new question opened and detailed description provided, the site could possibly assess *Is this* [adventure, campaign, plot, or whatever] *too complex for gamers brand new to role-playing?* The remainder are better asked on one of [these forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610).