# How does defense work?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, armor-class, defense

I'm new to D&D and I want to make a new character, he is a warlock with 11 hp and 13 armor class. What should I do when I get attacked? Damage - defense?

I don't have the books, I'm using D&D Beyond.

Comment: Related: [What do I need to run a D&D 5E campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56252)

Comment: Related: [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](/questions/11033)

Comment: Hello Gabriel, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! Kindly take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with our site. Are you reading the rules in English or translated?

Comment: Hi @gabriel Have you taken the time to look through the free official Basic Rules available from Wizards? I have a link [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules) for you in case you haven't.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question seems a little confusing to me; are you asking what happens if you are attacked? (There’s a lot of people leaving comments because somebody mentioned this in [chat], by the way)

Comment: Are you asking "what are good defensive tactics"? "How can I improve my character's defenses"?  "What are the mechanics my character has that affect how others attack me"?

Comment: Just to add one more person/comment to the dog pile: What rules *have* you read? It would be helpful if you could provide more information on what's confusing you. [DnDBeyond provides the basic rules for free](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) (along with the link RevenantBacon provides) so I would suggest reading through them then updating your question with more specific details about what you find confusing you if you're still unsure.

Comment: What role playing games have you played before trying D&D?  Some games use or apply defense differently than others.  It may be helpful for an answerer, in order to be helpful, to know what your frame of reference is.