# I am new to dnd, what are the main rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, new-players

I am new to Dungeons and Dragons. I've heard a lot about it, briefly played it, and know almost nothing about it. Can anyone help me out, want to play, and/or teach me how to play? My discord is on my profile and I am looking to play it with someone.

Comment: Also see this question: [What do I need to run a D&D 5E campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56252)

Comment: OK, I have [provided a link to the free rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf).  Welcome to RPGSE.  [Tour], [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] provide assistance on how to use this site, which has a restricted format. I will try to find a link we have on 'where to find people to play with' .. back in a bit.

Comment: For that, see this question: [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232)

Comment: See: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/52137 for our Q&A on that. RPG.SE is not a forum (take the [tour] for more on what we are) and so don't facilitate specific requests like that, but we do have a 
[list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137), many of which do.

Comment: @Parkerdaboss216 unfortunately, that's not what this site does. We are a Q&A site; you may be better off trying [a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566) to find a play group.

Comment: Also relevant then: [How do I know which edition of Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) the books I'm looking at are for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135571/14878)