# Discover a Monsters Weakness?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, skills, resistance

As a D&D5e newbie player, I'm getting to grips with all my skills and abilities and when to use them.

One thing that's come up is when we encounter monsters ... what do you roll against when trying to gauge a monsters weaknesses, so we can use fire, water, light, etc, against it?

Do different types of monsters require different rolls to understand what their possible weaknesses could be, eg Insight, Nature, Arcana, etc?

Some players round the table are GM's themselves and very knowledgeable about what to use against monsters, but their characters wouldn't have a clue, having never encountered them before, so it's difficult to find the right balance as a newbie who doesn't want to buy a monster manual or use an online search!

Comment: If this is for D&D 5e then it's probably a dupe of [Is there a spell, item, or other game feature that would give my character insight to an enemy's weaknesses and resistance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164670/14878) or [Is there a mechanic for a PC to learn the relative strength of an opponent, stat-wise?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159480/14878) or [What can PCs find out about creatures using knowledge skills?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90850/14878).

Comment: And also related for D&D 5e [Is it best practice to reveal monster information about resistances/vulnerabilities/immunities to the players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129662/14878)

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I'm trying to understand the "don't guess the system" policy.  Would you say that putting a tag would be inappropriate, answering would be inappropriate, but comments like your second and third are acceptable as encouraging the OP to tag themselves?

Comment: @Kirt when you put it like that that’s a reasonable point and may need to be something that’s clarified on [meta].