# How to make gunpowder ignite on a hand grenade

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

I'm trying to create a hand grenade that doesn't require a fuse.

My idea is small metallic oval container, gunpowder inside and a vial of some hind of liquid that when I throw it, would break the vial, spread the liquid which would ignite the gunpowder and BOOM!

Any idea of the type of Liquid that I should use?

If it's a easy to come by liquid even better.

Comment: Are you asking to use real physics to create this device? Because that's not really on-topic and up to whatever your DM will allow; not something we can answer here.

Comment: Not real physics, but something that could work on a magic world maybe

Comment: Why all the alchemical items and/or alchemist class are not an option?

Comment: it will be contained inside a small, compressed oval object (hand grenade basically)

Comment: My PC is not alchemist, but he is learning blacksmith and is now on a rampage trying to make new stuff. And he just loves everything thats related with explosions

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]. Unfortunately, the site isn't geared for scientific questions—about, for example, how an explosive delivery device that could *maybe* work in the real world would work in a game world—so those questions will be met with resistance. (There are a lot of variables in reality and game systems that make addressing such questions nearly impossible!) However, if the question were simply *How can I make or simulate in* Pathfinder *a totally mundane grenade?* the site can totally tackle that! Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use the rules for alchemy

What you are describing already exists in the system, in the form of [alchemical weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/alchemical-weapons/) (like a [Burst Jar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/alchemical-weapons/#TOC-Burst-Jar)), [alchemical substances](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances) (like a [Powder Ball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances/#TOC-Powder-Ball)), and [alchemist's bombs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Bomb-Su-). Maybe it isn't as strong as you want it to be, but the system is an abstraction, not a simulation of reality.

The game doesn't go into the chemical details on how alchemist fires work, or what exact components are used to create an alchemist's bomb, but the result is an explosive of some sorts, a **combustible throwable weapon created using alchemy**.

But you need [Craft(Alchemy)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) or a few levels on the [alchemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) class to pull that off, simply using your (meta) knowledge on how these things work in real life shouldn't be enough to allow your *character* to create those things.

On this [similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107086/is-it-metagaming-if-i-want-to-build-a-bomb/107087#107087), we see some good advice on how to avoid meta-gaming like this by thinking how our characters would think, being inquisitive about the world, checking up books, asking questions to people who might know the answer (*How gunpowder works?*). This will allow your GM to slowly introduce that kind of content to your character, and come up with creative ways to allow you to do what you want to do without house-ruling too much.

---

I have a friend who often will use modern *do-it-yourself* guides and try to come up with inventive technology in medieval times. Sometimes things that weren't invented until very recently, like a water-fueled motor, I kid you not.

Comment: +1. I know how to make it IRL. It really sounds and looks like alchemy. And if it walks like a duck, quacks like a duck... ;)

Comment: I have an Alchemist in my party, so one thing I could do would be work with him. Me making the shell of the bomb and let him make the explosive component. That way I wouldn't need to learn Alchemy

Comment: @RicardoAlves cooperative crafting like that is always a good idea. It will effectively reduce the total cost, since you are crafting some of the reagents (the casing).