# What spell or ability lets me detect a creature's resistances/vulnerabilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, vulnerability

I wonder if there is a spell that, when cast, gives me information about a certain creature, like its vulnerabilities and resistances. For instance, when fighting a Bronze Dragonborn, this spell would divine for me that they have Lightning Resistance.

Besides spells, is there a non-magical way to do so? Survival-check, Arcana, History, Insight? I have a hard time placing this under any one of those skills, if at all...

I'd be most interesetd in divination spells along the lines of Detect Magic / Detect Good and Evil, but if there is any other (magical) effect that would yield these results I'd like to know too.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate, especially since the OP commented saying the method did not specifically have to be a spell): "[Is there a spell that would give my character insight to an enemy's weaknesses and resistance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164670)"

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah, it's a dupe. That question wasn't suggested in the editor when I was rolling this one up, probably because of my poor tagging. The referred answer is kinda lacking though... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh no worries, duplicates aren't bad, in fact, they help later browsers and askers find these questions. I agree the current answer is a bit lacking (or perhaps it really is the only option), I'll add a bounty there since I'm curious as well